# Java JFormattedTextfield time formatting

Tags: java, swing, time, jformattedtextfield

I got some troubles using time in my code:

```
txtDauer = new JFormattedTextField();
txtDauer.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(
    new DateFormatter(DateFormat.getTimeInstance())));
```

When I use setValue(0) to the above FormattedTextfield the textfield shows 01:00:00 instead of 00:00:00.

The same problem occurs also at another line of the code with this method:

```
public static String convertLongToString(Long time) {
    String strtime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(time);
    return strtime;
}
```

Using this method with "0" it returns strtime = "01:00:00".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is the TimeZone**, your default computer's TimeZone is GMT +1.

The solution is setting GMT to +0:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

[Run and preview.](http://ideone.com/U3Gmk)

Answer (score 1):

For `Date`, `Date & Time` or `Time` use [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) with [SpinnerDateModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html#standard), example about using [SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9004170/714968)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replace my JFormattedTextfield with a JSpinner for 2 reasons: first, the textfield is not editable by the user and second its in fact a timer which can be controlled with start, pause and stop buttons. But anyway, thanks for your effort.