# Java Swing - I have a requirement to convert enter number to minutes and seconds in HH:MM format

Tags: java, swing, time, jspinner, jformattedtextfield

In Java Swing, do we have text component that will work just like how we set the time in Microwave.

By default system should display 00:00:00 (hh:mm:ss) in a textfield. 
Users focus defaults in the far right of the text box in the far right position. 
For example if user enters 00:00:85, then system should convert that to 01:25, similarly if user enters 00:08:99, then system should convert that to 00:9:39 (9 mins. 39 secs), similarly if user enters 00:03:00, then system should convert that to 00:03:00 (3 Minutes)

Please let me know if we have any component that works just like this or similar to this..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: ... just don't try to do it with a Calendar :)

Comment: You could have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield/11881681#11881681) which is a prototype of a time field (it has some issues, but should provide a jumping off point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, no. You will have to write some custom code.

You could use a `JFormattedTextField` with a custom format on it. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13424140/1076463) for an example. Only thing you will have to replace is the `Format` by your own format.

Another possibility is a `JSpinner` with a custom model where you just loop through a set of fixed values (e.g. incrementing time by 5''). This is how my microwave works. I can just rotate a button which increases the time. I cannot 'type' anything

Comment: Thank you Robin. I used JSpinner in this case but with slightly different solution to the user. Thank you for your time.