# Java - How can I add a clock in a JTextField with window builder?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, clock, windowbuilder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to constrain user to enter a time in a JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield)

I Use window builder in Eclipse, I've a JTextField and i want to set the hour as text (hh:mm:ss).
I've some troubles; does anybody can help me? thank you

Comment: *"I've some troubles;"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) & copy/paste any exception that results from it.

Comment: `JTextField.setText( "hh:mm:ss" )`. That is about all I can make from this question

Comment: I think you may want a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) see this answer for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield/11881523#11881523

Comment: As an "example", you could have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield/11881681#11881681) - it is a prototype, so it needs some more work, but it might inspire

Answer (score 0):

use java date & time. example:

```
import java.util.*;
...
  // Create a Gregorian calendar initialized
  // with the current date and time in the
  // default locale and timezone.
  GregorianCalendar gcalendar = new GregorianCalendar();

  String hr = ("" + gcalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":");
  String min = ("" + gcalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":");
  String sec = ("" + gcalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

then do:

```
<textFieldName>.setText(hr + min + sec);
```

that will change the text in the textfield to "HH:MM:SS"

Comment: He wants to create `JTextFild`