# I want to listen to changes in JtextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I really do not want to listen to DocumentListener. It generates too many events for me.
I am interested in listening only when the focus moves away from this specific JtextField.
Adding ActionListener will generate an event only when return key is pressed.
I would like to get it when the user moves away with a tab key or by moving the mouse away.
Is this possible?
Thanks and Regards

Comment: Sounds like you are after some validation mechanism. Consider using a `JFormattedTextField` in that case (see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424140/1076463))

Comment: +1 agreed with Robin. Seems like you want to validate the data in `JTextField`, which should rather be done using `JFormattedTextField`. See this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield/11881523#11881523

Comment: Alternatively have a look at `InputVerifier`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FocusListener. focusLost will help you when user moves to some other fields.

```
        JTextField jf = new JTextField();
        jf.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                // here you can have your code when user moves out
            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        } );
```

Comment: Rather use `FocusAdapter`as it allows the overriding of a single method.

Comment: All solutions look good to me. However for my immediate need focus lost event suffuses. Thanks all

Comment: @David. Yeah FocusAdapter would be good if there was need for only foculs lost event.Thanks for that..