# JFormattedTextField specific format

Tags: java, swing, format, document, jformattedtextfield

I need to make a JFormattedTextField following the format "00:00" with some requirements:

- The only changeable should be either of the "00". (So ":" should not be deletable)
- Tab makes you change between the two sides of the ":". (So having the cursor on one side and tabbing marks both "00" on the other side)
- Changing "00" to "2" should format it to "02".
- It's character limit should be 5 including the ":". (4 changeable characters)
- It should be initialized as "00:00", but it shouldn't be an acceptable input.
- You shouldn't be able to type in anything else than numbers. (Letters, symbols, negative numbers etc.)

Is there a way to do this? I have looked at different formatters, validators and Document Filter to add to the JFormattedTextField, but I'm not sure which ones to go with. (Using a DefaultFormatter right now, but have looked at a NumberFormatter for the limit. Will I need to use a combination of formatters and validators?)

This is my JFormattedTextField right now: http://pastebin.com/jW2RSJXe[1] .

Anything from code that does it to examples/pointers on what to look will be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think part 2 would be achievable.  You could take a look at [this time field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield/11881681#11881681) which cheats a little and uses two text fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this example. It uses a `MaskFormatter`. The `:` is there permanently, But I'm not sure how to format the other part of your question where if you only have 2, it'll show 02. You can play around with it

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class MaskFormatterTest extends JPanel {

    private JFormattedTextField formatText;

    public MaskFormatterTest() {
        formatText = new JFormattedTextField(createFormatter("##:##"));
        formatText.setColumns(20);
        formatText.setText("00:00");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JLabel("Enter only numbers"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(formatText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private MaskFormatter createFormatter(String s) {
        MaskFormatter formatter = null;
        try {
            formatter = new MaskFormatter(s);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException exc) {
            System.err.println("formatter is bad: " + exc.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return formatter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("MaskFormatter example");
                frame.add(new MaskFormatterTest());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The `MaskFormatter` sets the type value for each character at each position and the size allowed. In this case, I used `##:##`. Allowing two digits, a colon, and two more digits.

**Update:** Added `formatText.setText("00:00");` to code to initialize the text field.

Comment: Thanks! That got me really close to what I'm looking for!

Do you any good place to read about MaskFormatter or Formatter in general?

Comment: Check out [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#maskformatter) and the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html).