# show warning if users enter letter instead number in java applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, appletviewer

I am writing an tip calculator app in java applet with GUI, my question is how I make sure the error message will pop up if users enter letter instead of number

it is my first time asking question, please be easy on me! Thanks!!!

```
import objectdraw.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

// Typing in the text field and hitting return adds text to text area.
// Clicking on button erases the text area.
public class TextApplet extends Controller implements ActionListener 
{
    private static final int ROWS = 1; // rows in TextArea
    private static final int COLS = 10; // cols in text field & area

    private String amount;
    private float number;
    private JTextField inField, output;         // Input field

    private JButton clear, calc;     
         // button to clear output


    public void begin() 
    {

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();       // prepare text field & label
        JLabel inLabel = new JLabel("Bill Cost: ");
        inField = new JTextField(COLS);

        inField.addActionListener(this);
        JLabel topTitle = new JLabel("Tip Calculator", JLabel.CENTER);
        JPanel combinePanel = new JPanel();

        combinePanel.add ( inLabel );
        combinePanel.add ( inField );
        JPanel combinePanel1 = new JPanel();
        combinePanel1.add ( topTitle );

        topPanel.add ( combinePanel1 );
        topPanel.add ( combinePanel );


        topPanel.setLayout ( new GridLayout ( 3,1) );
        contentPane.add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();     // prepare text area & label
        JLabel outLabel = new JLabel("Bill + Tip:");
        output = new JTextField(COLS);
        output.setEditable(false);        // Prevent user from wrting in output
        centerPanel.add(outLabel);
        centerPanel.add(output);
        contentPane.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(); 

        // create button
        clear = new JButton("  Clear  ");
        calc = new JButton("Calculate");
        calc.addActionListener(this);
        clear.addActionListener(this);
        bottomPanel.add(calc);
        bottomPanel.add(clear);

        contentPane.add(bottomPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        validate();
    }

    // add text to area if user hits return, else erase text area
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        if (evt.getSource() == calc )
        { 
            amount = inField.getText();
            number = ( Float.parseFloat( amount ) );
            number = (15*number/100);

            output.setText ( Float.toString ( number ) + '$' );
        }

        else if (evt.getSource() == clear )
        {
            output.setText("$");
            inField.setText("");
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Friend I will give a suggestion

please add validation when call actionPerformed method

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
{
    if (evt.getSource() == calc )
    { 
       if(validate()){
        amount = inField.getText();
        number = ( Float.parseFloat( amount ) );
        number = (15*number/100);

        output.setText ( Float.toString ( number ) + '$' );

        }
     else{
   // show message for inter valid number or any other
       }
     }

    else if (evt.getSource() == clear )
    {
        output.setText("$");
        inField.setText("");
    }
 }
  boolean validate(){  

   try{
    amount = inField.getText();
        number = ( Float.parseFloat( amount ) );
      return true;

  }
   catch(Exception e){
   return false;

 }




 }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are any number of ways you might achieve this, you could use

- An [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)
- A [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)
- A [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)
- Or a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

Comment: +1 for the JSpinner. I always forget about that one.

Comment: @camickr Think you generally said it better ;)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [javax.swing.InputVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html).  That can be easily attached to a `JTextField`

```
JTextField inputField = new JTextField();
inputField.setInputVerifier(new NumericInputVerifier());

private class NumericInputVerifier extends InputVerifier
{
    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent input)
    {
        if (((JTextField) input).getText().matches("[0-9]+"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(input, "Only numbers are allowed", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

A complete [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/InputVerifierExample.htm) can be found here.

***Edit*** Added an example of how to use `InputVerifier` to limit to numeric input.  You'll want to double check the regex, but the basic idea is there...

Comment: InputVerifier just won't let the user leave the text field. It will still let them submit invalid entries and cause an action event.

Comment: Agreed.  If that doesn't meet OP's requirements, then there are other ways to solve this (as covered in other answers).  I'm also fond of using `JFormattedTextField`.  This has been discussed in the question [Best way to constrain user to enter a time in a JTextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield)

Answer (score 2):

Use a JFormattedTextField or a DocumentFilter. Then the user won't even be able to enter a non-numeric digit. See:

1. [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)
2. [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

For the document filter you will need to check each chraacter as it is entered to make sure it is a digit.

It is always better to do simple edits like that as the user types, rather than wait until you click on a button to do processing.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to call Float.parseFloat on a String that cannot be converted to a float, it will throw a NumberFormatException.  You need to catch this exception.

```
try {        
number = ( Float.parseFloat( amount ) );
number = (15*number/100);

output.setText ( Float.toString ( number ) + '$' );
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
//code to show error message here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well considering, you'd have to turn the string into an integer to do the math, you could do this:

```
try {
 int number = Ineger.parseInt(inField.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
//SHOW WARNING
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Label1.getText().matches("[0-9]+"))
// does Label1 containts numbers.
{
    // do math
}
else
{
    // warning
    Lavbel1.setText("");
}
```

Comment: This is for Applications and its verry simple.