# jSpinner time picker model editing

Tags: java, swing, timepicker, jspinner

I have jSpinner using for time picking. 
**Problem 1:** User can edited hour minutes and second seperator ":" and can write extra digits like "123"
**Problem 2:** model get always current time. I want "00:00:00" When i write this in code instead "hh:mm:ss" user can't edit the values.

My Code is;

```
spinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
SpinnerDateModel spinnermodel = new SpinnerDateModel();
spinnermodel.setCalendarField(Calendar.MINUTE);
spinner1 .setModel(spinnermodel);
spinner1 .setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner1 , "hh:mm:ss"));
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why the first problem is an issue?  The second problem can be fixed by using something like `Calendar` and setting the hour, minute and seconds fields to 0 and setting the spinners value to the result `Date` returned by `Calendar#getTime`

Comment: Problem1 issue because; spinner shows 00:00:00 if user delete 1 of ":" i cant get true format from the user. This must be a time picker. User interacts with only hours minutes and seconds and dont delete any character or add new character.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield/11881681#11881681), which is time field I've been tinckering with for awhile

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks to you for reference. I investigate it but really painful :) your code is very professional.

Comment: We had lots of issues with the spinner and user ability requirements that it was just simpler to create a need field/component. It still needs some tweaking, but the basic idea/intend is there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Problem 1: User can edited hour minutes and second seperator ":" and
>   can write extra digits like "123"

You can use the editor's formatter to accomplish this through [getTextField()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.DefaultEditor.html#getTextField%28%29) method:

```
JSpinner.DateEditor editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "HH:mm:ss");
DateFormatter formatter = (DateFormatter)editor.getTextField().getFormatter();
formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false); // this makes what you want
formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);
```

The text field is in fact a [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) with a [DateFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DateFormatter.html) as formatter. Take a look to [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for a better understanding on how to work with this component.

Note the pattern used when the editor is created. It's "HH:mm:ss" because of your 2nd requirement.

> Problem 2: model get always current time. I want "00:00:00"

You need to provide to your spinner with an initial date at 12 PM (24 hours) which will be translated in "00:00:00":

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();
model.setValue(calendar.getTime());

JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
```

---

#### Example

Here is a quite simple example to test what I've said. Hope it be helpful.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.DateFormatter;

public class Demo {

    private void createAndShowGUI() {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24); // 24 == 12 PM == 00:00:00
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();
        model.setValue(calendar.getTime());

        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);

        JSpinner.DateEditor editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "HH:mm:ss");
        DateFormatter formatter = (DateFormatter)editor.getTextField().getFormatter();
        formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false); // this makes what you want
        formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);

        spinner.setEditor(editor);

        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.add(spinner);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                
                new Demo().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

---

### Edit

> When user try manually write hours or minutes (not using arrows) some
>   logical problem ocures i think. Example i write 12 but spinner shows
>   21.

First off sorry I didn't note that before. This creepy behaviour happens because formatter's overwrite mode property is set to `false` somewhere during `JSpinner.DateEditor`'s initialization (but couldn't find where). This property is `true` by default according to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultFormatter.html#setOverwriteMode%28boolean%29). To solve this you only need to add this line (I've also edited my code above):

```
formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the Demo. When user try manually write hours or minutes (not using arrows) some logical problem ocures i think. Example i write 12 but spinner shows 21. And any way dont react minutes changes to hours ?

Comment: @BlackWhite please see my edit. Hope it works this time (it does for me at least). I think it also solves this: *"And any way dont react minutes changes to hours ?"*

Comment: Yes this is work. Still Minutes changes after 59 to 0 hours increase 1 time also seconds to minutes. Anyway not a big problem. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The JSpinner class was not specifically designed to be used as a time picker, so it can be difficult to customize its behavior. The **TimePicker** class in the [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker) library could be a better alternative for this usage.

You mentioned wanting to display the minutes and seconds in your format. The TimePicker format can be customized using the java.time DateTimeFormatter class.

Project Home page: https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker .

Screenshots of the components and the demo application are pasted below.

[image: DateTimePicker screenshot]
[image: Demo screenshot]