# Is there any way to limit input on jSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, timepicker, jspinner

How can I limit input of digits using jSpinner as a time picker?

When I use this code:

```
JSpinner.DateEditor editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "HH:mm");
DateFormatter formatter = (DateFormatter)editor.getTextField().getFormatter();
formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false); // this makes what you want
formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);
```

I took this example from here: [Similar problem using jSpinner as time picker on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960236/jspinner-time-picker-model-editing)

So when I start typing right at the beginning 1111, then it works fine until I enter further digits, then it starts calculating and giving me "strange" output, like:

```
12:51
```

when I entered another 1 after 1111.
When I put `12h` time format, like:

```
JSpinner.DateEditor editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "HH:mm a");
```

then it works just fine, stopping at the end after forth digit and not allowing any other input. How can I get this behavior for 24h time format?

Comment: Personal opinion, I hate date/time entry using a `JSpinner`, it just doesn't do the job right and the entry process can just be a pain for users.  Sometime ago I wrote a prototype/proof of concept `TimeField` which takes a lot of the pain out of the process - have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield/11881681#11881681) for more ideas.  If you're stuck using a `JSpinner`, then you might be out of luck

Comment: You might also consider having a play around with some of the ideas presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960236/jspinner-time-picker-model-editing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515413/jspinner-exclusively-for-time)