# JTextArea Filters and/or Inputs of time (00:00:00) Java

Tags: java, swing, time, jtextarea, documentfilter

There's a section of my program where the user should have the ability to edit an amount of time. There will be a default amount of time already set but the user should be able to edit it if need be (00:00:00)
Would a single line JTextArea with limitations on what characters can be entered (only numbers obviously) and some kind of filter to not allow the colons to be edited be the way to go? Or is there something more simple?

Comment: I've used a custom `Document`, I've considered using a `DocumentFilter`, but in the end I simply made a [Time Field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield/11881681#11881681) instead...

Comment: Do you want time or duration information within the field?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Duration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, dealing with duration is a lot different, as many of the normal "validation" process can be discarded (for example, you don't really care about the hours, as the user might need to put 100 hours, for example)...

So, based on this [time field example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield/11881681#11881681), I stripped back the API and re-built it (it really need an over haul any way ;))

So I ended up with this duration field...

[image: Duration Field]

At it's heart, it's nothing more than a series of fields with `DocumentFilter`s, `DocumentListener`s, some key bindings and general automation to make it "look" like a single field...

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class DurationField extends AbstractTimeField {

    private HourDocumentFilter hourDocumentFilter;

    private JTextField secondField;
    private DocumentFilter secondDocumentFilter;
    private FocusListener secondFocusHandler;

    public DurationField() {
        setDuration(0, 0, 0);
    }

    public void setDuration(int hour, int minute, int seconds) {
        setHour(hour);
        setMinute(minute);
        setSeconds(seconds);
    }

    public long getDuration() throws NumberFormatException {

        int hour = getHour();
        int minute = getMinute();
        int second = getSecond();

        return (hour * 60 * 60 * 1000)
                        + (minute * 60 * 1000)
                        + (second * 1000);

    }

    @Override
    public void setHour(int hour) {
        setFieldValue(getHourField(), hour, 3);
    }

    public void setSeconds(int seconds) {
        setFieldValue(getSecondField(), seconds, 2);
    }

    public int getSecond() throws NumberFormatException {
        return Integer.parseInt(getSecondField().getText());
    }

    @Override
    protected JTextField createHourField() {
        JTextField field = super.createHourField();
        field.setColumns(4);
        return field;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getHourFocusForwardLength() {
        return -1;
    }

    protected int getSecondFocusForwardLength() {
        return 2;
    }

    protected JTextField createSecondField() {
        JTextField secondField = new JTextField(2);
        ((AbstractDocument) secondField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(getSecondDocumentFilter());
        secondField.addFocusListener(getSecondFocusHandler());
        secondField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        secondField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MoveFocusForwardHandler(secondField, getMinuteFocusForwardLength()));
        return secondField;
    }

    @Override
    protected JComponent[] getTimeFields() {
        return new JComponent[]{
            getHourField(),
            new JLabel(":"),
            getMinuteField(),
            new JLabel("."),
            getSecondField()
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected List<JComponent> initFocusTransveralOrder() {
        List<JComponent> order = super.initFocusTransveralOrder();
        order.add(getSecondField());
        return order;
    }

    @Override
    protected void installKeyBindings() {
        super.installKeyBindings();

        JTextField minuteField = getMinuteField();
        installKeyBinding(
                        minuteField,
                        JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED,
                        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD, 0),
                        "toSecondField",
                        new MoveFocusForward());

        installKeyBinding(
                        minuteField,
                        JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED,
                        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0),
                        "afterMinuteArrow",
                        new MoveFieldFocusForward(minuteField, true));
        installKeyBinding(
                        minuteField,
                        JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED,
                        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD6, 0),
                        "afterMinuteKeyPad",
                        new MoveFieldFocusForward(minuteField, false));

        JTextField secondField = getMinuteField();
        installKeyBinding(
                        secondField,
                        JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED,
                        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0),
                        "beforeSecond",
                        new MoveFieldFocusBackward(minuteField, true));
        installKeyBinding(
                        secondField,
                        JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED,
                        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4, 0),
                        "beforeSecond",
                        new MoveFieldFocusBackward(secondField, false));
    }

    public JTextField getSecondField() {
        if (secondField == null) {
            secondField = createSecondField();
        }
        return secondField;
    }

    @Override
    protected DocumentFilter getHourDocumentFilter() {
        if (hourDocumentFilter == null) {
            hourDocumentFilter = new HourDocumentFilter();
        }
        return hourDocumentFilter;
    }

    protected DocumentFilter getSecondDocumentFilter() {
        if (secondDocumentFilter == null) {
            secondDocumentFilter = new SecondDocumentFilter();
        }
        return secondDocumentFilter;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the focus listener used to monitor the hour field
     *
     * @return
     */
    protected FocusListener getSecondFocusHandler() {
        if (secondFocusHandler == null) {
            secondFocusHandler = new SecondFocusHandler();
        }
        return secondFocusHandler;
    }

    protected void secondFieldLostFocus(FocusEvent evt) {
        String text = getSecondField().getText();
        if (text.length() < 2) {
            text = pad(text, 2);
            getSecondField().setText(text);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hour field focus handler. This watches for focus lost events a automatically pads the field with a leading "0" if the field is only 1 character in length
     */
    protected class SecondFocusHandler extends AbstractFocusHandler {

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            secondFieldLostFocus(e);
        }
    }

    protected class HourDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        @Override
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            System.out.println("insert: offset = " + offset + "; text = " + text);
            super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attr);
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

            try {
                // We convert the value here to make sure it's a number...
                int value = Integer.parseInt(text);
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            }
        }
    }

    protected class SecondDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        @Override
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attr);
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

            try {
                boolean isAcceptable = false;

                // How long is the text been added
                int strLength = text.length();
                // Convert the value to an integer now and save us the hassel
                int value = Integer.parseInt(text);

                // If the length is only 1, probably a new character has been added
                if (strLength == 1) {
                    // The valid range of values we can accept
                    int upperRange = 9;
                    int lowerRange = 0;

                    // Is the value acceptable..
                    if (value >= lowerRange && value <= upperRange) {
                        isAcceptable = true;
                    }
                } else {
          // Basically, we are going to trim the value down to at max 2 characters

                    // Need to know at what offest...
                    // 2 - offset..
                    // offset == 0, length = 2 - offset = 2
                    // offset == 1, length = 2 - offset = 1
                    strLength = 2 - offset;
                    String timeText = text.substring(offset, strLength);
                    value = Integer.parseInt(timeText);
                    if (value >= 0 && value <= 59) {
                        // Pad out the value as required
                        text = pad(value, 2);
                        isAcceptable = true;
                    }
                }

                if (isAcceptable) {
                    super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And the abstract parent class...

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FocusTraversalPolicy;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public abstract class AbstractTimeField extends JPanel {

    private DocumentFilter minDocumentFilter;
    private FocusListener hourFocusHandler;
    private FocusListener minuteFocusHandler;

    private JTextField hourField;
    private JTextField minuteField;

    private JPanel pnlFields;

    private List<JComponent> focusOrder;

    public AbstractTimeField() {

        initUI();
        installKeyBindings();

    }

    protected void initUI() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(getTimeFieldsPanel(), gbc);

    }

    protected void installKeyBindings() {

        JTextField hourField = getHourField();
        installKeyBinding(
                        hourField,
                        JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED,
                        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK),
                        "toMinuteField",
                        new MoveFocusForward());
        installKeyBinding(
                        hourField,
                        JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED,
                        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0),
                        "afterHourArrow",
                        new MoveFieldFocusForward(hourField, true));
        installKeyBinding(
                        hourField,
                        JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED,
                        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD6, 0),
                        "afterHourKeyPad",
                        new MoveFieldFocusForward(hourField, false));

        JTextField minuteField = getMinuteField();
        installKeyBinding(
                        minuteField,
                        JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED,
                        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0),
                        "beforeMinuteArrow",
                        new MoveFieldFocusBackward(minuteField, true));
        installKeyBinding(
                        minuteField,
                        JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED,
                        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4, 0),
                        "beforeMinuteKeyPad",
                        new MoveFieldFocusBackward(minuteField, false));

    }

    protected JPanel getTimeFieldsPanel() {

        if (pnlFields == null) {

            pnlFields = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            pnlFields.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border"), new EmptyBorder(0, 2, 0, 2)));
            pnlFields.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("TextField.background"));
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            for (JComponent field : getTimeFields()) {
                field.setBorder(null);
                pnlFields.add(field, gbc);
                gbc.gridx++;
            }

        }

        return pnlFields;

    }

    protected JComponent[] getTimeFields() {
        return new JComponent[]{
            getHourField(),
            new JLabel(":"),
            getMinuteField()
        };
    }

    protected List<JComponent> initFocusTransveralOrder() {
        List<JComponent> focusOrder = new ArrayList<>(3);
        focusOrder.add(getHourField());
        focusOrder.add(getMinuteField());
        return focusOrder;
    }

    protected List<JComponent> getFocusTraversalOrder() {
        if (focusOrder == null) {
            focusOrder = initFocusTransveralOrder();
        }
        return focusOrder;
    }

    protected int getHourFocusForwardLength() {
        return 2;
    }

    protected int getMinuteFocusForwardLength() {
        return 2;
    }

    protected JTextField createHourField() {
        JTextField hourField = new JTextField(2);
        ((AbstractDocument) hourField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(getHourDocumentFilter());
        hourField.addFocusListener(getHourFocusHandler());
        hourField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        hourField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MoveFocusForwardHandler(hourField, getHourFocusForwardLength()));
        return hourField;
    }

    public JTextField getHourField() {
        if (hourField == null) {
            hourField = createHourField();
        }
        return hourField;
    }

    protected JTextField createMinuteField() {
        JTextField minuteField = new JTextField(2);
        ((AbstractDocument) minuteField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(getMinuteDocumentFilter());
        minuteField.addFocusListener(getMinuteFocusHandler());
        minuteField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        minuteField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MoveFocusForwardHandler(hourField, getMinuteFocusForwardLength()));
        return minuteField;
    }

    public int getHour() throws NumberFormatException {
        return getFieldValue(getHourField());
    }

    public int getMinute() throws NumberFormatException {
        return getFieldValue(getMinuteField());
    }

    protected int getFieldValue(JTextComponent field) throws NumberFormatException {
        return Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
    }

    public void setHour(int hour) {
        setFieldValue(getHourField(), hour, 2);
    }

    public void setMinute(int minute) {
        setFieldValue(getMinuteField(), minute, 2);
    }

    protected void setFieldValue(JTextComponent field, int value, int padding) {
        String text = pad(value, padding);
        field.setText(text);
    }

    public JTextField getMinuteField() {
        if (minuteField == null) {
            minuteField = createMinuteField();
        }
        return minuteField;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the document filter used to filter the hour field
     *
     * @return
     */
    protected abstract DocumentFilter getHourDocumentFilter();

    /**
     * Returns the document filter user to filter the minute field
     *
     * @return
     */
    protected DocumentFilter getMinuteDocumentFilter() {
        if (minDocumentFilter == null) {
            minDocumentFilter = new MinuteDocumentFilter();
        }
        return minDocumentFilter;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the focus listener used to monitor the hour field
     *
     * @return
     */
    protected FocusListener getHourFocusHandler() {
        if (hourFocusHandler == null) {
            hourFocusHandler = new HourFocusHandler();
        }
        return hourFocusHandler;
    }

    /**
     * Used the focus listener used to monitor the minute field
     *
     * @return
     */
    protected FocusListener getMinuteFocusHandler() {
        if (minuteFocusHandler == null) {
            minuteFocusHandler = new MinuteFocusHandler();
        }
        return minuteFocusHandler;
    }

    public static String pad(long lValue, int iMinLength) {
        return pad(Long.toString(lValue), 2);
    }

    public static String pad(int iValue, int iMinLength) {
        return pad(Integer.toString(iValue), iMinLength);
    }

    public static String pad(String sValue, int iMinLength) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(iMinLength);
        sb.append(sValue);
        while (sb.length() < iMinLength) {
            sb.insert(0, "0");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    protected void hourFieldLostFocus(FocusEvent evt) {
        if (!evt.isTemporary()) {
            String text = getHourField().getText();
            if (text.length() < 2) {
                text = pad(text, 2);
                getHourField().setText(text);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void minuteFieldLostFocus(FocusEvent evt) {
        if (!evt.isTemporary()) {
            String text = getMinuteField().getText();
            if (text.length() < 2) {
                getMinuteField().setText(text + "0");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void installKeyBinding(JComponent field, int condition, KeyStroke keyStroke, String name, Action action) {
        InputMap im = field.getInputMap(condition);
        im.put(keyStroke, name);

        ActionMap am = field.getActionMap();
        am.put(name, action);
    }

    protected void moveFocusToNextField(JComponent parent) {
        List<JComponent> order = getFocusTraversalOrder();
        Component current = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
        if (current == parent) {
            int index = order.indexOf(current);
            if (index != -1) {
                if (index == order.size() - 1) {
                    transferFocus();
                } else {
                    JComponent next = order.get(index + 1);
                    next.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            } else {
                transferFocus();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void moveFocusToPreviousField(JComponent parent) {
        List<JComponent> order = getFocusTraversalOrder();
        Component current = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
        if (current == parent) {
            int index = order.indexOf(current);
            if (index != -1) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    transferFocusBackward();
                } else {
                    JComponent previous = order.get(index - 1);
                    previous.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            } else {
                transferFocusBackward();
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract class AbstractFocusHandler extends FocusAdapter {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            if (e.getComponent() instanceof JTextComponent) {
                JTextComponent field = (JTextComponent) e.getComponent();
                field.selectAll();
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Hour field focus handler. This watches for focus lost events a automatically pads the field with a leading "0" if the field is only 1 character in length
     */
    protected class HourFocusHandler extends AbstractFocusHandler {

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            hourFieldLostFocus(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Minute field focus handler, watches for focus lost events and automatically adds a "0" to the end of the field if it is only 1 character in length
     */
    protected class MinuteFocusHandler extends AbstractFocusHandler {

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            minuteFieldLostFocus(e);
        }

    }

    protected class MoveFocusForwardHandler implements DocumentListener {

        private JTextComponent parent;
        private int maxLength;

        public MoveFocusForwardHandler(JTextComponent parent, int maxLength) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.maxLength = maxLength;
        }

        public int getMaxLength() {
            return maxLength;
        }

        public JTextComponent getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            documentChanged(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            documentChanged(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            documentChanged(e);
        }

        protected void documentChanged(DocumentEvent e) {
            if (getMaxLength() > 0) {
                if (e.getDocument().getLength() >= getMaxLength()) {
                    moveFocusToNextField(getParent());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * The document filter used to filter the minute field.
     */
    protected class MinuteDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        @Override
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attr);
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

            try {
                boolean isAcceptable = false;

                // How long is the text been added
                int strLength = text.length();
                // Convert the value to an integer now and save us the hassel
                int value = Integer.parseInt(text);

                // If the length is only 1, probably a new character has been added
                if (strLength == 1) {
                    // The valid range of values we can accept
                    int upperRange = 9;
                    int lowerRange = 0;
                    if (offset == 0) {
                        // If we are at the first edit position, we can only accept values
                        // from 0-5 (50 minutes that is)
                        upperRange = 5;
                    }

                    // Is the value acceptable..
                    if (value >= lowerRange && value <= upperRange) {
                        isAcceptable = true;
                    }
                } else {
          // Basically, we are going to trim the value down to at max 2 characters

                    // Need to know at what offest...
                    // 2 - offset..
                    // offset == 0, length = 2 - offset = 2
                    // offset == 1, length = 2 - offset = 1
                    strLength = 2 - offset;
                    String timeText = text.substring(offset, strLength);
                    value = Integer.parseInt(timeText);
                    if (value >= 0 && value <= 59) {
                        // Pad out the value as required
                        text = pad(value, 2);
                        isAcceptable = true;
                    }
                }

                if (isAcceptable) {
                    super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
                    if (fb.getDocument().getLength() == 2) {
                        moveFocusToNextField(getMinuteField());
                    }
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            }
        }
    }

    public class TimeFocusTraversalPolicy
                    extends FocusTraversalPolicy {

        private List<Component> order;

        public TimeFocusTraversalPolicy(List<Component> order) {
            this.order = new ArrayList<>(order.size());
            this.order.addAll(order);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot,
                        Component aComponent) {
            int idx = (order.indexOf(aComponent) + 1) % order.size();
            return order.get(idx);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getComponentBefore(Container focusCycleRoot,
                        Component aComponent) {
            int idx = order.indexOf(aComponent) - 1;
            if (idx < 0) {
                idx = order.size() - 1;
            }
            return order.get(idx);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getDefaultComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return order.get(0);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getLastComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return order.get(order.size() - 1);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getFirstComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return order.get(0);
        }
    }

    public class MoveFocusForward extends AbstractAction {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            moveFocusToNextField((JComponent) e.getSource());
        }

    }

    public class MoveFocusBackward extends AbstractAction {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            moveFocusToPreviousField((JComponent) e.getSource());
        }

    }

    public class MoveFieldFocusForward extends AbstractAction {

        private JTextComponent field;
        private final boolean ignoreNumLock;

        public MoveFieldFocusForward(JTextComponent field, boolean ignoreNumLock) {
            this.field = field;
            this.ignoreNumLock = ignoreNumLock;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            boolean numLockOff = false;
            try {
                // Get the state of the nums lock
                numLockOff = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_NUM_LOCK);
            } catch (Exception exp) {
            }
            if (ignoreNumLock || !numLockOff) {
                if (field.getCaretPosition() >= field.getDocument().getLength()) {
                    moveFocusToNextField((JComponent) e.getSource());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class MoveFieldFocusBackward extends AbstractAction {

        private JTextComponent field;
        private final boolean ignoreNumLock;

        public MoveFieldFocusBackward(JTextComponent field, boolean ignoreNumLock) {
            this.field = field;
            this.ignoreNumLock = ignoreNumLock;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            boolean numLockOff = false;
            try {
                // Get the state of the nums lock
                numLockOff = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_NUM_LOCK);
            } catch (Exception exp) {
            }
            if ((ignoreNumLock || !numLockOff) && field.getCaretPosition() <= 1) {
                moveFocusToPreviousField((JComponent) e.getSource());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The abstraction is for my benifit, from here I can build a `TimeField` as well :)

Comment: @OscarF There's a lot in there, it's meant to solve my problems, from a design point of view, but I've tried to make it as flexible as I could...

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use a JFormattedTextField. I've written a simple example. Just run it, type something into the box, and hit tab to change focus (and thus update the label).

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;
    import javax.swing.text.*;

    public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements DocumentListener {
      private JFormattedTextField ftf;
      private JLabel output;
      private DateFormat myFormat;

      public MyPanel() {
        this.setFocusable(true);

        myFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);

        ftf = new JFormattedTextField(myFormat);
        ftf.setValue(new Date());
        this.add(ftf);

        output = new JLabel("--:--:--");
        this.add(output);

        ftf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
      }

      public void update() {
        // get the time
        Date date = (Date)ftf.getValue();

        // display it
        output.setText(myFormat.format(date));
      }

      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { update(); }
      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { update(); }
      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { update(); }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(640, 480);

        frame.add(new MyPanel());

        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Technically, maybe, but as a use, I can enter whatever I like, the field only provides post validation...what happens when the user removes the entire contents and tries updating the field?? This is also not a good solution if the OP is after entering a duration

Comment: The JFormattedTextField will only accept valid input. I believe the default behavior is commit-or-revert, where it will attempt to update the value when it loses focus, but will revert to the most recent valid value if it can't.

Comment: I had no end of problems while testing your example and I kept breaking it.  IMHO it doesn't work "extremely" well in these situations.  I also prefer real time/immediate feedback/validation but that's just me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JSpinner** to achieve this. I hope the below piece of would help.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Date Picker");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JSpinner timeSpinner = new JSpinner( new SpinnerDateModel());

JSpinner.DateEditor timeEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(timeSpinner, "HH:mm:ss");
timeSpinner.setEditor(timeEditor);
timeSpinner.setValue(new Date());

frame.add(timeSpinner);

frame.setVisible(true);
frame.pack();
```

Comment: Just beware, this will only allow 0-23 hours, this is not a good solution for durations...